# Updating data in complex XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am writing a function to update my XML and am having some issues. I'd hoped I could just set old XElement directly to the updated one but that doesn't work in the foreach loop (though should only ever be one query result). I was going to hard-code each field, but then decided to use a loop. However when it hits the  section and it's sub-elements it reads it all as a single element and messed up the file

```
var myDevice = from c in appDataXml.Descendants("device")
               where (string)c.Element("name") == App.CurrentDeviceName 
                      && (string)c.Element("ip") == App.CurrentIp
               select c;

if (myDevice.Any())
{
    foreach (XElement device in myDevice)
    {
        //device.Element("customname").Value = updatedDevice.Element("customname").Value;

        for (int a = 0; a < device.Elements().Count(); a++)
        {
            string field = device.Elements().ElementAt(a).Name.ToString();
            device.Element(field).Value = updatedDevice.Element(field).Value;
        }
    }
}
```

sample XML

```
<Devices>
  <device>
    <name>blah</name>
    <customname>custom</customname>
    <ip>192.168.1.100</ip>
    <port>1000</port>
    <sources>
      <source>
        <code>00</code>
        <name>blah2</name>
        <hidden>False</hidden>
      </source>
      <source>
      ...etc
    </sources>
  </device>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to abstract (make classes) of your xml, it will help you CRUD and search it.

Example: (using these extensions: http://searisen.com/xmllib/extensions.wiki)

```
public class Device
{
    const bool ELEMENT = false;
    const bool ATTRIBUTE = true;

    XElement self;
    public Device(XElement self) { this.self = self; }

    public string CustomName 
    { 
        get { return self.Get("customname", string.Empty); }
        set { self.Set("customname", value, ELEMENT); }
    }
    public string Name { get { return self.Get("name", string.Empty); } }
    public string Ip { get { return self.Get("ip", "0.0.0.0"); } }
    public int Port { get { return self.Get("port", 0); } }

    public Source[] Sources
    {
        get { return _Sources ?? (_Sources = self.GetEnumerable("sources/source", xsource => new Source(xsource)).ToArray()); }
    }
    Source[] _Sources;

    public class Source
    {
        XElement self;
        public Source(XElement self) { this.self = self; }

        public string Code { get { return self.Get("code", string.Empty); } }
        public string Name { get { return self.Get("name", string.Empty); } }
        public bool Hidden { get { return self.Get("hidden", false); } }
    }
}
```

An example using it:

```
XElement xdevices = XElement.Load(file.FullName);
Device[] devices = xdevices.GetEnumerable("device", xdevice => new Device(xdevice)).ToArray();
var myDevice = devices
     .Where(d => d.Name == App.CurrentDeviceName 
              && d.Ip == App.CurrentIp);

foreach (Device device in myDevice)
{
    string name = device.Name;
    foreach (Device.Source source in device.Sources)
    {
        string sourceName = source.Name;
    }
    device.CustomName = "new name";
}
xdevices.Save(file.FullName);
```

It is a change in the way of thinking, so instead of worrying about how to reference a value, you create the class to read/write to the xml, and instead you just get/pass off data to a class, that then reads/writes the xml.

Edit:
**---- Add to XElementConversions class ----**

To be consistent with the file, and to work properly I made detailed versions.  You can modify them to make the other types, like bool, DateTime, etc.

```
public static int GetInt(this XElement source, string name, int defaultValue)
{
    source = NameCheck(source, name, out name);
    return GetInt(source, source.GetDefaultNamespace() + name, defaultValue);
}

public static int GetInt(this XElement source, XName name, int defaultValue)
{
    int result;
    if (Int32.TryParse(GetString(source, name, null), out result))
        return result;
    return defaultValue;
}
```

Comment: It looks like it's important that this is a Windows Phone 7 project - TypeDescriptor the extender uses doesn't appear to be implemented

Comment: You can try and create your own: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx

Comment: Or, you can create `GetInt()`, `GetBool()`, etc that uses the `GetString()` for example int, `GetInt() { return Convert.ToInt32(GetString(...)); }`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to implement this

Comment: Added to bottom of post two GetInt()'s one takes a string element name, and other a more complicated namespace and element name.

Comment: Forgive me, I'm new to C# and I don't fully understand this class - how to I incorporate this new code into the public static T Get<T> that is trying to use TypeDescriptor?

Comment: comment out the Get() function and paste in the GetInt() code, and create the GetBool() by changing the name and the word `int` to `bool` and change `Int32` to `bool` etc for whatever types you need.

Comment: Got it working, overlooked the obvious... thanks for sticking with me.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that `var myDevice = ... select c;` will produce at most 1 element?

If so then replace the hole `.Any()` and `foreach()` with a `.Single()`:

```
var myDevices = ... select c;
var myDevice = myDevices.Single();  // exception when Count != 1
```

And then I see no reason why this wouldn't work:

```
 myDevice.Element("customname").Value = updatedDevice.Element("customname").Value;
```

Comment: That line does work, but I did a loop so I wouldn't have to do a line for each field, ie ip, port, and then I wasn't sure about handling the sources sub-items

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `XElement.Value` but iterate over the `XElement` elements within your device `XElement` and change their `XText` nodes. Alternatively you could use `XAttribute` so you don't need to make so many nested elements.

```
<Devices>
 <Device Name="blah" IP="192.168.1.100" Port="1000">
   <Sources>
     <Source Code="00" Name="blah2" Hidden="false"/>
   </Sources>
 </Device>
</Devices>
```

`XElement.Value` is a concatenated string of all the `XText` nodes that are a descendant of the `XElement`. If you `set` it, you consequently overwrite all the sub elements. Read more on [XElement.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.value.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the [XElement.Value Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.value.aspx). Use the [XElement.ReplaceWith Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.replacewith.aspx). Value's getter outputs

> A String that contains all of the text content of this element. If there are multiple text nodes, they will be concatenated.

which means that the subelements' tags will be stripped out.

Try this line instead of using Value:

```
device.Element(field).ReplaceWith(updatedDevice.Element(field));
```